# Make web service work on different server

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap, android-ksoap2

I am developing a web service with Eclipse. This service will be accessed from Android with `ksoap2`.

I successfully tested the service on my local apache tomcat (`http://localhost:8080/`) and now want to set this service up on a different server (i.e. `http://giraffe/`).

The `.wsdl` file generated by Eclipse contains the following line:

```
<wsdlsoap:address location="http://localhost:8080/AndroidService/services/AndroidService"/>
```

I guess this won't work out if I just add the `.war` file to `giraffe` and try to reach the service.

My question now is the following: What do I need to change in order to be able to use this service on a different server? Do I just have to change this `address location`?

If you need me to post some of the code/files, just tell me.

My eclipse project structure looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `http://localhost:8080` on wsdl with `http://giraffe/`

Are you facing any issue once you deploy on the server?

Comment: The problem is that I tried changing `http://localhost:8080/AndroidService/services/AndroidService` to `http://localhost:8080/AndroidService` on my localhost and it didn't work. So I want to make sure I don't break anything before deploying this to the other server.

Comment: Can I know to which server are you deploying ? axis2 or any other one?

Comment: It should be axis2. I'm not entirely sure. Any easy way to find it out?

Comment: How you deploy the file ? aar or any other format ? Do you know the folder structure in the server?

Comment: Also provide structure in your eclipse project

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22751/discussion-between-baz-and-fahad)

Comment: Yes, just have to change address location, even without that service will work fine, only concern will be while generating client part using WSDL.

Comment: Turned out that I didn't have to change anything. Just deploy the `.war` file. Thanks anyway :)